Access to "ConsoleHost_history.txt" denied on Windows PowerShell
I am trying to run a file on python but the following error message is rendered:

Error reading or writing history file
'C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt':
Access to the path
'C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt'
is denied.

The line I am entering is the following:

py "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Waterfall Chart 2.py

What could be the issue causing this error message to be displayed?
Greetings!

Said path is where PowerShell's PSReadLine module persists the history of interactively typed commands, and the current user should normally have full access to that file. You'll need to investigate why your permissions are different and restore them.

User/jbrah path only the admin and the user can read/write the file.

Thank you for your answer. I tried the code line another time after rebooting the computer and another error message is rendered: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, while the file path is 100% correct.

There's definitely something unusual going on, but without additional information I doubt anybody will be able to help. Have you tried recreating the file and its folder? New-Item -Force C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt

I had a Local account using a Microsoft Account Profile by pointing to the existing profile with Desktop, OneDrive assets in place
Because the different account types default to Local or Roaming respectively [I think] things got ugly eventually & I had issues with Python, NPM, ReactJs etc
I Used netplwiz to set the Local folder to my c:\users\username
Run sysdm.cpl then click User Profile to set your profile type to Roaming or Local
Clean up any Group Policy irregularity

Can you clarify as to what the Group Policy issue was that prevented running commands in PowerShell?
